# Para que sirve estas etiquetas? Angular

Tags: angular

Alguien me puede explicar para que sirve estas etiquetas:

```
 #email="ngModel"


[(ngModel)]="user.email"
```

De este fragmento de codigo:

```
   <input type="email" #email="ngModel" name="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" class="form-control" required />
```

Comment: #email="ngModel" que haces referencia a la variable a una variable email como ngModel (declaras una variable local email). [()] haces un binding en dos sentidos [(target)]="expression"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> El símbolo numeral (`#`) indica que se creará una **Template reference variable**, la cual es una variable que es una referencia al elemento DOM del template en donde se declara.

La siguiente instrucción:

```
input type="email" #email name="email" />
```

Crea una variable que referencia al elemento `input`, por consiguiente, podemos hacer algo como:

```
{{ email.value }}
```

O en el controlador:

```
@ViewChild('email') email: TemplateRef<HTMLInputElement>

const emailInput = this.email.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement
emailInput.value // o .focus() o cualquier propiedad/método disponible en HTMLInputElement
```

**¿Qué significa el valor asignado a `email`?**

La instrucción `#email="ngModel"` significa lo siguiente:

> Dentro de la variable de referencia `email` se guardará la directiva `ngModel` **asociada con este control**.

Esto te va a permitir acceder a propiedades útiles como `dirty`, `valid`, `enabled`, `valueChanges`, etc.

---

Por otro lado, el siguiente código:

```
<input type="email" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.email">
```

Simplemente indica que existirá un [two-way data binding](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/one-and-two-way-data-binding-angular) entre ese control y la variable `email` del objeto `user`.

Esto, resumiendo, significa que dicho control está ligado tanto en *input* como *output* con la variable `user.email`, lo que significa una comunicación **bidireccional**: los cambios que se realicen tanto sobre el input como en la variable `user.email` se verán reflejados en el mismo.

Comment: *baia, baia*, el maestro Gustavo ha regresado a predicar con el ejemplo ;)